# How to filter pandas Dataframe to remove last row of the same type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which represents origin , destination, and departure_dates  for trains that looks something like this:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({
          'org': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
          'des': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
          'eff_departureDate': ['20200101', '20200102', '20200103', '20200101', '20200102']
})
```

```
org  |  des  | eff_departureDate
-----+-------+-------------------
  A  |   a   |   20200101
  A  |   a   |   20200102
  A  |   a   |   20200103
  B  |   b   |   20200101
  B  |   b   |   20200102
```

I need to create a column which indicates weather there are future dates for same origin & desstination.

```
org  |  des  | eff_departureDate | has_future_dates 
-----+-------+-------------------+------------------
  A  |   a   |   20200101        |   True
  A  |   a   |   20200102        |   True
  A  |   a   |   20200103        |   False
  B  |   b   |   20200101        |   True
  B  |   b   |   20200102        |   False
```

and the filter the dataframe based on this new column.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the current dates are smaller than the maximum date for each group, which can be calculated with `groupby.transform('max')`:

```
df['has_future_dates'] = df.eff_departureDate < df.eff_departureDate.groupby([df.org, df.des]).transform('max')

df
  org des eff_departureDate  has_future_dates
0   A   a          20200101              True
1   A   a          20200102              True
2   A   a          20200103             False
3   B   b          20200101              True
4   B   b          20200102             False
```

---

Or use `groupby.apply`:

```
df['has_future_dates'] = df.eff_departureDate.groupby([df.org, df.des]).apply(lambda s: s < s.max())

df
  org des eff_departureDate  has_future_dates
0   A   a          20200101              True
1   A   a          20200102              True
2   A   a          20200103             False
3   B   b          20200101              True
4   B   b          20200102             False
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse sort the df, drop duplicates and join back to the original dataframe to get the last time for each org/des combination:

```
df1 = df.merge(df[::-1].drop_duplicates(subset=['org','des']),on ['org','des'],suffixes=['','_next'])
```

Then simply see if the last departure time is the same as this one:

```
df1['next_available'] = df1['eff_departureDate'] != df1['eff_departureDate_next']
```